# How to move nested routing into separate urls.py?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I was wondering if I could get your help on this.

I have a urls.py which contains the following:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
# AccountViewSet in accounts app
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet) 
# ProjectViewSet in projects app
router.register(r'projects', ProjectViewSet) 

accounts_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'accounts', lookup='account')
# AccountProjectsViewSet in projects app
accounts_router.register(r'projects', AccountProjectsViewSet)
```

As you can see, accounts and projects are quite closely connected due to nested routing.

I'd like to move the accounts routing logic into accounts/urls.py, and the projects routing logic into projects/urls.py.

My attempts at this so far cause the following error:

```
RuntimeError: parent registered resource not found
```

Is it even possible to separate this logic, or does it need to be together?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Facing the same problem, and I have no clue what I did wrong!

Comment: Please add the current solution also